# How to add all new files in a directory to CVS

Tags: cvs

I'm writing a Java app that manages building/deploying my apps. I'd like it to look in the project for any new files/folders that haven't been added to CVS and add them. I can use `cvs add` to add the individual files/folders, but how can I programmatically determine which need to be added? The app will run on a windows machine.

Comment: Probably the best way to get a solution would include riding in a DeLorean to 10 years ago and asking someone then!

Comment: ...Oh wait no it didn't. Turns out I don't live in a science fiction movie as much as it might seem so at times. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output from:

```
cvs -n add
```

The `-n` will prevent anything from being changed, so you get a nice list of files that would have been added.

An alternative would be to parse the CVS Entries files. to compare against exising names yourself.